# What are the possible outcomes when joining the tables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Table A has 10 records, table B has 100 rows. The relationship between A and B is 1:N. What are the possible outcomes when joining the tables?
The possible answers answers are (there may or may not be more than one):

100 rows, using A INNER JOIN B

10 records, using A LEFT JOIN B

10 records, using A RIGHT JOIN B

10 records, using A FULL OUTER JOIN B

100 records, using A FULL OUTER JOIN B

Minimal number of output rows is 10

Maximal number of output rows is 1000

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I can sort of see the first option happening only

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how about you?

Comment: Is this about SQL? Or is it just phrased in SQL-like  code?

Comment: But not exactly sure of what 'inner join', 'left join', 'right join', 'full outer join' means?

Comment: Maybe play a bit with this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn't there other ways of explaining this other than sql as I have no experience in that?

Comment: OP has asked the same question at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448700/what-are-the-possible-outcomes-when-joining-inner-outer-left-right-the-tabl).